# Loop an array and send the result to view ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have database retrieved data that is stored in an array. That array contains some JobID's. I want loop through those JobIds and find a match from the database and display it in a view. There can be more than 1 JobIds in the array.

What I did so far:

```cs
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string[] arr = GetAgentJobId();
    int[] ids = arr.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
    List<Requisition> Requisitions = _context.Requisitions.ToList();
    for (int i = 0; i <= ids.Count(); i++)
    {
        var req = from r in Requisitions
                  orderby r.JobID descending
                  where r.Status == "Approved" && r.JobID == ids[i]
                  select r;
        
            return View(req);
    }
    return View();
}
```

I put return `View(reg)` inside the loop. I think the problem is because the `i++` is unreachable. How can I return this `View(req)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fragment of an action method:

```
    var list = arr.Select(int.Parse).ToList();
    var model = _context.Requisitions.Where(e => list.Contains(e.JobID) && e.Status == "Approved").OrderByDescending(r => r.JobID).ToList();
    return View(model);
```

And the model in the view might be defined as `@model IEnumerable<Requisition>` or `@model IList<Requisition>`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's going to return on the very first match.  Remove the inside return, add the req to a new array and then loop through the entire list of JobIds.  Return the new array to the view once all of the JobIds are matched.